# Gestionar asincronia REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un componente que recibe datos por props.
Con estos datos intento hacer varios metodos de array para poder utilizarlos.
A veces me funciona, pero otras veces me da error.
Poniendo que "quantity" por ejemplo es undefined, o que "dataShopping.orderLineList.map" is not a function.

Supongo que es un fallo por la gestion de la asincronia, que intento ejecutar estos metodos antes de que llegue la respuesta, pero no se como gestionarlo.

mi codigo es:

```
export default function ShoppingBannerSummary(data) {
    // console.log(data.data)
    const dataShopping = data.data
let quantity =  dataShopping.orderLineList.map((x)=>
x.quantity
)
console.log(quantity)
let quantityTotal = quantity.reduce((a,b)=> a+b,0)
console.log(quantityTotal)

  return (
etc....
```

creo que intento hacer quantity y quantityTotal antes de que datashopping tenga resultado

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar el componente padre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la información que compartiste, asumo que declaraste la variable state como un arreglo vacío en el componente padre, por lo que puedes tomar la decisión de si tu variable tiene datos que cargue el componente que quieres, ejemplo:

```
{ arreglo.length > 0 ? <ShoppingBannerSummary data={data} /> : null }
```